# docker-compose build fails with weird python errors

Tags: docker, compilation, docker-compose, proxies

> docker-compose build
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "docker-compose", line 6, in 
>       File "compose/cli/main.py", line 68, in main
>       File "compose/cli/main.py", line 118, in perform_command
>       File "compose/cli/command.py", line 37, in project_from_options
>       File "compose/cli/command.py", line 91, in get_project
>       File "compose/config/config.py", line 368, in load
>       File "compose/config/config.py", line 534, in process_config_file
>       File "compose/config/validation.py", line 393, in validate_against_config_schema
>       File "compose/config/validation.py", line 450, in handle_errors
>       File "site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 105, in iter_errors
>       File "site-packages/jsonschema/_validators.py", line 304, in properties_draft4
>       File "site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 121, in descend
>       File "site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 105, in iter_errors
>       File "site-packages/jsonschema/_validators.py", line 16, in patternProperties
>       File "site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 121, in descend
>       File "site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 105, in iter_errors
>       File "site-packages/jsonschema/_validators.py", line 212, in ref
>       File "site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 375, in resolve
>       File "site-packages/functools32/functools32.py", line 400, in wrapper
>       File "site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 385, in resolve_from_url
>       jsonschema.exceptions.RefResolutionError: HTTP Error 400: Bad request"

Comment: Where do you get this error? How does your docker-compose file look like?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking, including your code, other alternatives you've tried, and what you are trying to accomplish? That will help other provide relevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

unset default_proxy

this unsets the default proxy. this allows you do "docker-compose build" or only other option is use "sudo docker-compose build" on your mac.